# Split wordpress sub-menu into two columns

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I tried some code snippets to split wordpress sub-menu into two colums and I got some success. But they are not fully splitted. There is white space beneath odd menu-items and white-space above even menu-items. [Link for Menu](https://www.nawishta.com/)

In the above web page, Menu --> Nawishta Prime Time --> Season 2

It seems the menu-items are not in line and creating white gaps. Following is the CSS code I used:

```
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li {
    clear: initial;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
} 
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 300px;
}
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}
```

I applied this class "sub-menu-columns" on the menu item "Season 2" in wordpress menu settings.

What I need is to remove gaps like:
[image]

Comment: how are you expecting this to look?

Comment: @HowardE Please see the post now, I added the screenshot. I need to remove these gaps that I highlighted using box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough space for your elements to be next to each other. With using `margin` you are taking up the space, so it breakes to the next line.

Please remove the `margin-right: 300px;` This is not the right way to go.

There are multiple ways to achieve what you like.

You can set a width for your menu, so the child elements now how to stretch the 50% you have defined:

```
.sub-menu { width: 480px; }
```

Using this, your columns will align next to each other.

If you do not want to use a fixed width, you can for example use CSS grid to define how the child columns should look like:

```
.sub-menu { display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; }
```