# Creating columns in Wordpress sub menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've created a sub menu with two columns in Wordpress but it's far from perfect yet. [You can see it here](https://roamaniac.com/) - it's under Blog >> Mountains.

[It currently looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zir6r.png)

[I want it to look something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhjnH.png)

Code I've used so far:

```css
/* Sub menu columns */

.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu.dropdown li {
    display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 175px 175px;
    width: 50%;
} 

.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
}
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(even) {
    float: left;
}

.top-bar-section .dropdown li:not(.has-form):not(.active) > a:not(.button) {
    line-height: 45px;
    width: max-content;
}
```

Issues I'm having:

1. Longer names do not fit in the box
2. On mobile only part of the names in the right-hand column is visible

Questions I'm trying to get answered:

1. How do I get two neat sub-menu columns that fit in their box and are neatly spaced out?
2. How do I tidy this up on mobile? Probably with a media query, but what should I put in it?

Solutions I've tried and do not work for me, or at least not 100%:

- [Split wordpress sub-menu into two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745400/split-wordpress-sub-menu-into-two-columns)
- https://www.phpcluster.com/how-to-split-wordpress-submenu-in-2-column/
- I've tried adding  `justify-content: space-evenly;`  or  `justify-content: space-around;`  to `.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu.dropdown li`   which creates the box I want on my computer but makes things worse on mobile.
- As per SA Bappy's instructions below I've inserted `.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu { column-count: 2; column-gap: 10px; }` and removed `.top-bar-section .dropdown li:not(.has-form):not(.active) > a:not(.button) { line-height: 45px; width: max-content; }`, which give me the box I want *but* the left-hand column spills off the page and the text is centered, not aligned left. Any suggestions to improve that specific solution?

Completely out of my depth here, so any input it hugely appreciated! I'm really hoping I can work my way out of this one using CSS only because I'm pretty new to this coding thing.

**Solution**

Thanks to the amazing SA Bappy I've solved this thing like this:

```
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu {
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 10px;}

.sub-menu-columns .sub-menu li {
  max-width: 250px;}

ul#menu-main-menu ul ul {right: unset; left: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS column property.

```
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've applied that, but now the columns are so wide that they flow off the screen to the left. Any further suggestions to amend that?

Comment: Use max-width on your sub-menu li

Comment: Thanks, that kind of helps but since some of the names are rather long the max-width required still makes the box spill off the page to the left. Any chance I could make the sub menu open to the right?

Comment: Can you send me the link to your website?

Comment: Sure: http://roamaniac.com/ (Blog >> Mountains)

Comment: `
ul#menu-main-menu ul ul {
    right: unset;
    left: 100%;
}
`
Use this one

Comment: You are officially amazing! This makes my day. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question though to make sure I understand what I'm doing; why are there two ul's after the class? Is that because it's a sub menu, i.e. a ul under a ul? ` ul#menu-main-menu ul ul { `

Comment: ul#menu-main-menu - > Its your main menu

Comment: ul#menu-main-menu ul -> It's your sub menu

Comment: ul#menu-main-menu ul ul -> It's your sub sub menu

Comment: Welcome again!!

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the min-width in the columns width, this way you can have a minimum width for all the columns, or you can even set different min-widths to each column.

Comment: Thanks! I've set max-width to 250px, it looks like using min-width will get me exactly the same result in this situation?

Comment: Not really, max-width tells the element to not go over the value you set. Min-width tells the element to not shrink less than the value you set. On your case I would use min-width.

Comment: Makes sense, especially if I'm going to use even longer names in the menu...

Comment: How do I set different min-widths for each column? Because right now the columns are still really wide.

Comment: to set different min-widths you have to assign different classes or id's to each column